# an error produce while i MAKE in the installation of freeradius server

Tags: installation, makefile, freeradius

this is an error i got ,when i use command ***`MAKE`*** while installation of freeradius server,if anybody would aware about this kind of error. kindly give me some hand to get out from this error!!!.

```
amsys@amsys-ThinkPad-R61:~/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5$ make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5'Making all in libltdl...
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/libltdl'
/usr/bin/make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-   2.2.5/libltdl'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/libltdl'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/libltdl'
Making all in src...
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/src'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/src'
Making all in include...
/usr/bin/make -w -C include all
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/src/include'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/src/include'
Making all in lib...
/usr/bin/make -w -C lib all
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/src/lib'
/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/libtool --mode=compile   --tag=CC gcc -I/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5 -I/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/src -g -O2 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -DNDEBUG -I/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/libltdl -D_LIBRADIUS -I/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/src -c debug.c
make[4]: /home/amsys/Downloads/radius: Command not found   
make[4]: *** [debug.lo] Error 127
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/src/lib'
make[3]: *** [lib] Error 2  
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/src'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2  
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5/src'
make[1]: *** [src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/amsys/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5'
make: *** [all] Error 2
amsys@amsys-ThinkPad-R61:~/Downloads/radius dp c/freeradius-server-2.2.5$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build and use its own libtool, but that doesn't seem to be working, so i'd advise you to install libtool from packages distributed with your OS.